# Regexp to find 3 digit int in string

Tags: go

I have a DNS query that is returning the fields I need, but now I need to parse a 3 digit number from the response.

The reponse block I am parsing looks like this:

```
_ref: "network/ZG5zLm5ldHdvcmskMTAuMC45MS4wLzI0LzA:10.0.91.0/24/default"

comment: "Vlan xyz site number 777 "

network: "10.0.91.0/24"

network_view: "default"
```

This looked like the right regexp, but I'm not getting a response:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
fmt.Println(re.FindAllString("%s", -1))
```

Comment: There are no digit characters in the string `"%s"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation for `regexp.FindString(string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindString) to make sure you've got the arguments right; you should be giving it the search string...

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\d{3}`)
search := "Vlan xyz site number 777 "
match := re.FindString(search)
fmt.Printf("OK: %q\n", match)
// OK: "777"
```